# mysql_fetch_assoc returning array from primary key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm attempting to use a form post to add rows to a mySQL table. Each row has a primary I'm calling quoteID. When a new form is submitted, it should add itself as a row in the table, with a quoteID of one greater than the previous quoteID. It current looks something like this:

```
<?
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:login.php");
}
include 'verify.php';
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","$password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("internal", $con);

$previousOrderID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sourcingQuote ORDER BY quoteID DESC LIMIT 1"); 
$previousOrderID = mysql_fetch_assoc($previousOrderID);
$newOrderID = $previousOrderID['ID'] + 1;

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

At the moment there are 4 rows in this table, with quoteID's of 1,2,3 and 4. The odd thing is, if I attempt:

```
<? echo $previousOrderID; ?><br>
<? echo $newOrderID; ?><br>
```

The output result is:

```
Array

1
```

Why isn't $newOrderID displaying 5? and the value $previousOrderID 4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your uniqueid is called quoteID; you're looking for ID:

```
$newOrderID = $previousOrderID['ID'] + 1;
```

Try this:

```
$newOrderID = $previousOrderID['quoteID'] + 1;
```

You're currently getting 1 because when it's not finding a value, it's returning null, which evaluates to 0 when you add 1 to it.

You can also get around this by making the quoteID field an auto_increment one.